# Java recurrence relation with for loop

Tags: java, recurrence

```
public int algo(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    algo(n/2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know that the recursive call will mean it is `T(n/2)` but how will the for loop affect the recurrence relation?

EDIT: My attempt.

I think that the for loop will run `log n` times because it is run every time `algo(int n)` is run. And `algo` is run log n times because n keeps on being divided by 2. Also, the for loop runs for 4 iterations. So I think it will add an extra `4 log n` to the recurrence so it will be O(n) = T(n/2) + 4 log n.

Comment: After your edit, you aren't using the value from recursing. Anyway, yes it's `O(log n)`

Comment: Are you using little o, because O(_n/2_) is just O(_n_). It's also not right, your algorithm is O(log _n_)

Comment: @Ogen. I see, I think your attempt is trying to do too much at once. The recurrence relation only models one step, on which the for-loop only prints 4 times, not 4 log _n_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

since the for loop is constant time , and does not vary with n . It should not affect the time complexity.

Comment: You missed the recursion.

Comment: I did not. I was responding to the question - if the for loop would make difference to time complexity . I see your point, due to recursion, the time will be according to this time series n + n/2 + n/4 ..+ 1 which is  O(log(n)) .

Answer (score 2):

Here you are divinding n by 2 in each recursive call and the `for loop` is not depending on the input n,so the time complexity is `O(logn)`.
Time complexity added by `for loop` is constant so it will be discarded.

While calculating time complexity,you have to worry about what is varying with input.Here your `for loop` is not dependent on input `n`,so it is not eligible while calculating time complexity.

Comment: I think you mean `O(log n)`. It's definitely not linear.

Answer (score 0):

To be specific the for-loop's effect on the recurrence relation is **trivial** at best. Without the for loop your recurrence relation would be:

*T<sub>n</sub>* = *T<sub>n/2</sub>* + *c*

Where *c* is the overhead from checking `n==1` and method calls and returns. The for-loop always prints exactly 4 times, and so always executes in *k* operations. The new recurrence relation is:

*T<sub>n</sub>* = *T<sub>n/2</sub>* + *c* + *k*

Excitingly ... we still have a constant (*c*+*k*) where we had *c* before so we'll get the same O(log *n*).